# Is md5(md5(password).salt) secure?

Tags: passwords, hash, salt, md5

I know md5 is considered non-secure but what if someone used md5(md5(password).salt) instead? Isn't this technically better / more secure?

Comment: Let's say somebody finds an attack that can crack an hash from a hash function within a day. If it's a general attack it will work for *every* hash so H(password) and H(H(password)) are both hashes of the same size and thus vulnerable to the same attack and crackable in exactly the same time.

Comment: if you repeated the inner one 10,000 times before hashing, it would be somewhat safer by making it hard to run on dedicated hardware (ASICs) and prevent pre-rolled cracker profiles from working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash  `md5(md5(password).salt)` is just as secure as `md5(password.salt)` .

All the difference i can see is the additional MD5 calculation `md5(password)` which increases the computing time the attacker needs to spend by a little and it may not be going to make a big difference.

Lets say the attacker takes the most used 100 passwords like `welcome,monkey` with md5 values 
`40be4e59b9a2a2b5dffb918c0e86b3d7,d0763edaa9d9bd2a9516280e9044d885` respectively.

He need to brute force  password as well as salt in `md5(md5(password).salt)` using the list `welcome,monkey` .

Example:`md5(md5("welcome").salt)`

**He can simple do away with that additional MD5 calculation by using the list of md5 values calculated one time.**

Example: `md5("40be4e59b9a2a2b5dffb918c0e86b3d7".salt)`

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess the same is also known as [Meet In The Middle Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack).

Answer (score 2):

Such combinations are often supported out of the box by password cracker tools. Have a look at the [algorithms of hashcat](http://hashcat.net/hashcat/#features-algos) you will see a lot of similar combinations. MD5 is not appropriate to hash passwords because of its speed, brute-forcing is ways too easy (about 100 Giga MD5 per second), so no it is not secure.

Answer (score -1):

**No**

When you are using md5(md5(password).salt) method it's as strong as md5(password.salt). It seems, that it need more time to find a collision when you are using md5(md5(password).salt) method. In that case, you can use bcrypt to manually slow down the collision attack operation. And using old md5 - bad idea.

Comment: This adds nothing new to the other answers.